# Defender repeats quarantine operation endlessly in OneDrive temp folder

Tags: windows, virus, windows-defender, virus-removal

I get these notifications endlessly, every few minutes, basically forever and I don't know what to do about them. The name changes a little, but the notifications just keep coming forever. Is this known behaviour with some way to resolve?

file: D:\OneDriveTemp\S-1-5-21-1187308099-1743664786-759309126-1001\DACF5170EA779AF4!143-DACF5170EA779AF4!658046-DACF5170EA779AF4!662278-90da10004c8f6fafdaa2cf18922670a745564f45.temp

[image]

Comment: Try whitelisting what is in the One Drive temp folder.

Comment: Is that safe or advisable? I see what you mean and it's probably ok, but what is Defender up to - I mean, Defender and OneDrive are both Microsoft products, can't they play nice with each other... :(

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, you have a file stored on OneDrive, which is being synced from the cloud down to your local PC. Windows Defender considers that file malicious and removes it from the PC. OneDrive then syncs, "notices" the file is not on your local drive, and downloads it again... *ad nauseam*.

How did the file get to OneDrive's cloud repository in the first place?

One possibility: it might have been a file such as one of [Nirsoft's password recovery tools](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/), that Microsoft at one time ignored and now considers a liability (personally, I believe such tools are innocuous).

Another possibility: the file is in a huge archive such as a rescue boot ISO, and was uploaded before Defender had time to find it in the ISO.

A third, and more serious issue: that file appears to be a Windows Registry file, implying your machine is, or has been *infected with malware*. In that case, a **thorough** scan by Defender and by a third-party tool, such as [Malwwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/mwb-download) or an alternative is needed, and the offending files must be removed from OneDrive, as well. [If the Registry *is* compromised](https://sensei-infosec.netlify.app/forensics/registry/persistence/2020/04/15/malware-persistence-registry.html), it may be very difficult to remove malware, perhaps requiring complete reformatting of the drive after attempting to salvage data with external tools.

How to break out of this loop?

- Stop [OneDrive syncing](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-to-cancel-or-stop-sync-in-onedrive-4885c27e-3d89-4d69-be75-2646c71367d3) and delete the file.
- **Temporarily** [turn off Windows Defender real-time security](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/turn-off-defender-antivirus-protection-in-windows-security-99e6004f-c54c-8509-773c-a4d776b77960) and delete the file from OneDrive and the local folder.